# Union Tool returns an not-before-seen error in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, union

'NoneType' object has no attribute 'isGeosEmpty'

Above the error I get when attempting to combing two polygons of the same spatial extent, but of course with two different sets of information. Both have same projection defined. not sure why this isn't working. Do the attribute tables have to have at least one column of similar information?

Answer (score 2):

Attributes should not affect it. The [isGeosEmpty](http://qgis.org/api/1.8/classQgsGeometry.html#ad916e0bc26c5ddc2616ee77008f8e4aa) error is likely due to errors in geometry. As quoted from the link:

> check if geometry is empty using GEOS

---

You can check/fix these errors using:

- The **Geometry Checker** plugin which can be downloaded/enabled from the menu bar:

  ```
  Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins...
  ```
- The GRASS tool **v.clean** which can be accessed from the *Processing Toolbox*.

Comment: Is the Geometry Checker not available anymore in QGIS 2.18.7? I have the exact proble as stated above, but cannot install the plugin.... Thanks!

Comment: @Rob - It's become a core plugin so you should already have it installed for QGIS 2.18. Is it not listed in `Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins...`?

Comment: Yes it is, but the buttons Reinstall and Uninstall Plugin are out of function. So probably it's incorporated. I tried the method from Steven down here (try Union with the valid Output layers), but still the problem persists...

Comment: @Rob - Yes, those buttons are disabled. If you enable the plugin (i.e. check the box) then you should be able to find the plugin from the menubar: `Vector > Geometry Tools > Check Geometries`.

Comment: Check! Thnx @Joseph!

Comment: @Rob - Most welcome! Glad you found it :)

Answer (score 2):

Joseph's right about the cause. I'll expand on that answer, as I've just stumbled across a very similar (but slightly different) error tonight..

> **'NoneType' object has no attribute 'difference' See log for more details**

I was digitizing some abstract shapes and got into a bit of a mess with the snapping tool... fixing the geometries in-place didn't seem to work though.

It seems that in QGIS 2.16 it's possible to have **two** Geometry checkers - the first one in the menu is based on the plugin. This is the one available in versions before 2.16

The second is near the bottom of the menu, and is the one which uses the Processing replacement for Ftools. (It's in the same sub-menu as Densify Geometries etc.) See screenshot below.

[image]

I found if I used the Processing one, and ran Union etc. on the "Valid Output" layers, it **did** work. I'm not sure why there's a difference, but it worked for me. I used the 'GEOS' option in the 'Method' combobox.

That won't help if you're using an older version of QGIS than 2.16 - Joseph's suggestion of GRASS `v.clean` will be a better bet if that's the case.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, but cannot fix it. I tried both Geometry Checkers. The "Check Geometries" and the "Check validity". I tried with respectively the repaired ones and the Valid Outputs, but still the same problem. What do you mean with "I used the 'GEOS' option in the 'Method' combobox"? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved for me by using the tool vector / geometry / densif geometry (qgis 2.18.18), then i use the new layer for cut and the error it s gone.