# How to overlap and merge layers in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, layers, merge, overlapping-features

I have two layers (1 and 2) and I want to overlap them and the intersection and the union didn't work.

I want to get something like this:

[image]

Is it really easy or is there a special method to follow ?

I am working with QGIS.

Comment: In what way did Intersection and Union not work?  Can you [edit] your question to include details of how you used these?

Comment: Are both layers Vector layers?

Comment: There are both vector layers. I did both Union and Intersection without any special settings and I got the same error as they did here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/204505/union-tool-returns-an-not-before-seen-error-in-qgis . I have to go to sleep it's too late here, see you tomorrow and thanks for answering.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question to include any additional information or clarification.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First use 'Symetrical Difference' instead of 'Intersection' in the Geoprocessing toolbox and then in a second step do 'Union'.
  [image]
The yellow triangle in 2. is spatially in the same location as in 1. yet I didn't knew how to illustrate it in a better way. I hope you get what I mean.
That should do the same thing and didn't raised any errors for me (QGIS 2.18.0 on MacOS 10.11.6)

Comment: Using "Symmetrical difference", I had elements without geometry left in the table. I recommend using "difference" in order to get rid of those.